# Android 2.2 compileJava error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

When i try to run my app with android studio 2.2 its giving me compileJava error like this.

> cannot access Transform class file for
>   org.simpleframework.xml.transform.Transform not found

Could any one please help me to understand this issue. I will appreciate it very much.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue like this. Add the following snippet to you app's `build.gradle`

```
andriod {
packagingOptions {
        /**
         * The following two lines are added to resolve an error with
         * Android studio 2.2 version's duplicate file exception
         */
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```